# Alternative for Windows firewall

Tags: windows, gratis, security

My system runs on Windows 8. I am not satisfied with the performance of Windows firewall. So I need an alternative for it.

It should be light, fast and free. Which is a good one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [TinyWall](http://tinywall.pados.hu/) for my firewall solution. I help managing a Web Hosting company that uses TinyWall for our game servers that run on Windows. It is also recommended by several technology sites.

Comment: Also, I do help manage a Web Hosting company that does use TinyWall for our game severs that runs on Windows

Comment: @NickWilde I decided to add the reason why I recommended it as a comment to my answer instead of adding it into the actual answer. Sorry. And the link has been added.

Comment: Please don't do this in future. Comments are: A) overlooked, B) may be put though automatic/manual purge periodically.

Comment: Why? Windows firewall is pretty powerful. Why replace it, and what benefits to does this have?

Comment: @Jacob My main issue with Windows 8 and Windows overall is that they tend to hide features within their GUI. TinyWall is minimalistic while getting the job done without hiding features.

Comment: Even on the Sever editions?

Comment: @Jacob Sadly, but yes.

Comment: TinyWall is NOT a firewall, contrary to what advertising says. It's just a "nice" front end to the built-in Windows Firewall. Basically, it's just a botched down version of the `firewall with advanced security` control panel applet.